# Defensive Aid replacing Evasion. Optional?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monk

The Nimble Guardian Racial Archetype (monk) for catfolk in Pathfinder replaces evasion with defensive aid at lvl2. Is this optional? DM's discretion? I kinda like evasion better.

Comment: 65BAJA, you know that you are not limited to the racial archetypes, right? (you can use the "standard" Monk, or a different archetype). No offense, but it seems that the Nimble Guardian differs from the Monk in that he is better at guarding others (which is based on **Defensive Aid**, which you don't want) and turning into a large feline - maybe a different build will better suite your tastes?

Comment: I'm playing a pair of catfolk, brother & sister (same litter lol). It fits with the image I have for the pair. I just need to learn how to role-play to the strengths of the class. I'm having fun with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [PFSRD – Class Archetypes](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/class-archetypes):

> **When an archetype includes multiple alternate class features, a character must take them all**—often blocking the character from ever gaining certain standard class features, but replacing them with other options. All other class features of the base class that aren't mentioned among the alternate class features remain unchanged and are acquired normally when the character reaches the appropriate level, unless noted otherwise. A character who takes an alternate class feature does not count as having the class feature that was replaced for the purposes of meeting any requirements or prerequisites.

(**emphasis** mine)

So yes, you must take Defensive Aid. I can’t speak to that specific ability, but in many cases archetypes intentionally give a weaker replacement for one feature in order to give a stronger replacement to another feature.

Comment: I had a question about this, is the monks Qiddong monk the only exception because it says you 'can' swap out ablities? Thus it stacks with all the other archtypes?

Comment: @DanceSC Quiggong monk is an exception, yes; whether or not it is the *only* exception, I don't know. d20PFSRD captured an [FAQ entry explaining the process](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo---monk-archetypes/qinggong-monk).